# Slicing numpy array to several arrays every x number of cells

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D numpy array that I want to divide to several arrays, based on the number of cells (x) in each array.

For example, if this is the array:

```
[0, 2, 7, 9, 13]
```

and `x=2`

I want to get the following arrays as a result:

```
[0,2]
[7,9]
[13]
```

I feel that there is a simple way to do it without using loops, but I couldn't find it.

Thank you!

Comment: So, you want a list of arrays? Because a single array as output isn't possible.

Comment: No, I want to get several arrays as a result

Comment: Also, it would be best to stick to loops for performance that is.

Comment: Please share the code what have you tried so far?

Comment: And clear your intension of output... U just wanted to Print these sub arrays OR returning these many sub arrays from function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.asarray([0, 2, 7, 9, 13])    
x = 2
np.split(A, range(x, len(A), x))  
# [array([0, 2]), array([7, 9]), array([13])]
```

Note that as @Divakar mentioned in his comment, you are better off performance wise  using loops (or in this case a list comprehension).

```
def f(seq, n):
    return [seq[i:min(i + n, len(seq))] for i in range(0, len(seq), n)]

def g(seq, n):
    return np.split(seq, range(n, len(A), n))

%timeit f(range(12345), 109)
65.2µs ± 468ns (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit g(range(12345), 109)
1.32ms ± 5.21 µs (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

### Edit

Since slicing past the last index will naturally slice till the last element, we can do away with the check

```
def f(seq, n):
    return [seq[i : i + n] for i in range(0, len(seq), n)]
```